# TinyMCE make Firefox crash when editing a big HTML file

Tags: html, google-chrome, email, firefox, tinymce

I'm creating a email client application.
For the email editing editor I'm using TinyMCE but when i edit a big email (for example I'm fowarding a received email, i.e a Groupon email) all the browser crash.
But this happen only on Firefox. Chrome and IE works good. Why? What i can do?

Comment: do you get any javascript errors? which version of FF are you using?

Comment: I can't get javascript errors because all the browser crashes. It was FireFox 25 (i say 'was' because i temporary removed this feature and i will try with firefox 29)